# JSON Cache Program

Tags: python, json, file, api, cache

I have some code that is intended to be a package (so that it can be accessed via `import cachejson`).

Here is the code for the package:

The update variable is whether the user wants to update the file or retrieve the older file? (True means use the file should be overwritten, false means it should be used.)

```
import requests
import json
import os    

folder_name = 'json_cache'    

class cj(object):
    def __init__(self, url, update=False):
        self.url = url
        self.filename = self.make_filename() + '.json'
        self.update = update
        self.make_cache_directory()    

    def download(self):
        return requests.get(URL).json()    

    def save(self):
        # print('{}/{}'.format(folder_name, self.filename))
        with open('{}/{}'.format(folder_name, self.filename), 'w') as out:
            json.dump(self.raw, out)    

    def make_cache_directory(self):
        try:
            os.makedirs(folder_name)
            print('new cache folder...')
        except FileExistsError as e:
            pass    

    def make_filename(self): # make the filename for the saved json file
        new = self.url.replace('/', '=')
        new = new.replace(':', '-')
        return new    

    def file_exists(self): # see if the file already exists
        return os.path.isfile('{}/{}'.format(folder_name, self.filename))    

    def load(self): # json from file to python obj
        with open('{}/{}'.format(folder_name, self.filename)) as file:
            return json.load(file)    

    def json(self):
        if self.file_exists() and self.update == False:
            print('file exists...')
            return self.load()
        else:
            self.raw = self.download()
            self.save()
            print('new file saved...') 
            return self.raw
```

Then the usage would be something like:

```
repos = cachejson.cj(APIURL).json()
```

How can I improve this code to make it a better package?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I improve this code to make it a better package?

## Remove `print`s

It may have some debug value to you but your `print` calls will be the most annoying things for your future users. Few possibilities are there to remove it (I’m thinking about [`redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) to `/dev/null` for instance) but it add a lot of noise to a program. Besides you don't get such messages from other libraries: `defaultdict` don't say when they create the missing entry or they get the already existing one; `json.loads` don't print a success message; etc.

## Add documentation

If you're going to release it for use by others, you’ll want to at least populate the `help` of your module with meaninfull informations. Add docstrings at all levels: module, class and functions. Some of your comments should already be docstrings anyway.

## Use a standard folder location

I can `cd` anywhere on my filesystem and fire a Python console there. This will mean, each time, I’ll create a new `'json_cache'` folder and won't benefit from past downloads. Make your folder in a unique, centralized, location so any use will benefit from it. The `~/.cache/` folder seems a good fit.

## Use a better name

Your class `cj` is really, really badly named. Do not fear using the same name for a class/function than the name of the module. Look at `socket.socket`, `pprint.pprint` and others, it is worse to have a bad, simplified, name than to repeat yourself in such cases.

---

Other than that, I would change a few other things:

```
"""TODO: Module docstring"""

import os

import json
import requests


class cache_json(object):
    """Manage a JSON object through the cache.

    Download the associated resource from the provided URL
    when need be and retrieve the JSON from a cached file
    if possible.
    """

    CACHE_FOLDER = 'json_cache'

    def __init__(self, url, update=False):
        self.url = url
        self.filename = '{}.json'.format(url.translate({
            ord('/'): '=',
            ord(':'): '-',
        }))
        self.update = update
        self.make_cache_directory()

    @property
    def cache_folder(self):
        """Path to the cache folder"""
        return os.path.join(
                os.path.expanduser('~'),
                '.cache', self.CACHE_FOLDER)

    def download(self):
        """Perform the retrieval of the requested JSON data"""
        return requests.get(self.url).json()    

    def save(self, raw):
        """Save the provided raw JSON data into the cached file"""
        filename = os.path.join(self.cache_folder, self.filename)
        with open(filename, 'w') as out:
            json.dump(raw, out)

    def load(self):
        """Retrieve the saved JSON data from the cached file"""
        filename = os.path.join(self.cache_folder, self.filename)
        with open(filename) as cached:
            return json.load(cached)

    def make_cache_directory(self):
        """Create the cache directory if it doesn't exist"""
        os.makedirs(self.cache_folder, exist_ok=True)

    @property
    def file_exists(self):
        """Whether the cached file already exist"""
        filename = os.path.join(self.cache_folder, self.filename)
        return os.path.isfile(filename)

    @property
    def json(self):
        """The JSON data associated to the given URL.

        Either read from the cache of fetched from the Internet.
        """
        if not self.update and self.file_exists:
            return self.load()

        raw = self.download()
        self.save(raw)
        return raw
```

Note the use of `property`: the expected usage becomes:

```
repos = cachejson.cache_json(APIURL).json
```

Comment: That class name is still annoying. It should be `class CacheJson` to follow PEP8 conventions.

Comment: Also, in `download` method it should be `self.url` instead of `URL`. More, in `__init__` there's a missing `)` at the end of `self.filename` ;P

Comment: @MrGrj PEP8 says " Class names should normally use the CapWords convention.

The naming convention for functions may be used instead in cases where the interface is documented and used primarily as a callable.". The `socket.socket` class is an example.

Comment: @MrGrj Right for the `URL` parameter, just got it from the OP's code which, apparently, was broken to begin with.

Comment: Why use the `@property` annotation for those specific methods?

Comment: Also, why use `.translate` over `.replace`?

Comment: @werdna3232 Because the `property` feels better™. No strong rule here, it's just that these kind of information fits better as attributes, hence the `property`. For `translate`, this is because it can do all the required transformations in a single call, so Python does not need to allocate memory for intermediate strings.